# Sort a list of class by multiple parameters

Tags: vb.net, list, class, sorting

I have a list :

```
Dim mylist as List(Of myclass)
```

For example I have 1000 implemented objects in mylist.

This is the structure of myclass :

```
myclass.id  
myclass.value  
myclass.name 
myclass.comments
```

And for example I have the following :

```
myclass(0) = 1,10,'test00','abcde'
myclass(1) = 1,10,'test01','efgh'
myclass(2) = 1,22,'test00','www'
```

I want to sort in VB.NET the list mylist with 3 parameters : id, value, and name. And it is possible to have the same couple id,value,name on different objects.

I don't understand how can I sort this List with 3 parameters. I tried but it works only for one parameter....

Thanks for your help

EDIT : this is the code I use for sorting with 1 parameter :

```
        For index = 1 To mylist.Count - 1

            Dim x As myclass= mylist(index)
            Dim j As Integer = index

            While (j > 0 And mylist(j - 1).id> x.id)
                mylist(j) = mylist(j - 1)
                j = j - 1
            End While

            mylist(j) = x

        Next
```

Comment: Can you show how your sorted with one paramter?

Comment: Yes, take a look I just edited my question

Comment: I believe you can order by multiple parameters using LINQ.  The syntax is basically the same as writing a SQL query (which is, after all, the whole point of LINQ).  First put your classes in a list, then create a second sorted LINQ list;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never used LINQ before, now I have to read documentation about that. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following LINQ Query:

```
 Dim SortedList As List(Of myclass) = mylist.OrderBy(Function(m) m.id).ThenBy(Function(m) m.name).ToList()
```